# unable to get output using between operator

Tags: php, mysql

i am just new to php and mysql; i have an fname,lname,bdate on my table; I have a mysql query that pulls up the age from date of birth save in mysql;

```
 SELECT FNAME, LNAME, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, BDATE, CURDATE()) AS AGE FROM perinfo
```

what i wanted to do is filter the output by group such ages 10 to 19, ages 20 to 29 etc. i made some research about it and found that between operator can do it but im wondering why it is not working; i added it to my query but it does not give me any output.

```
 WHERE AGE BETWEEN 10 and 19
```

could it be because AGE is not a column on my table and was just assigned for the query i have created? is there a possible way to correct this? any help is much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed.

Means you can't use an alias name in a `where` clause. Use

```
SELECT FNAME, LNAME, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, BDATE, CURDATE()) AS AGE 
FROM perinfo
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, BDATE, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 10 and 19
```